# UIView gradient does not change on second save

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm creating a preview from something that people can configure in settings. They can choose a color in settings.

**My view hierarchy:**

- Settings (Choose color for tree, and preview tree)
- Choose color for tree (Here the user can choose for colors of the tree, with a save button)

I have an `unwindSegue` for my save button, that calls the `setupCell` method. **But the background gradient layer of my UIView does not want to change.**

**Code:**

```
- (IBAction)setupCellSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
    [self setupCell];
}

-(void)setupCell{
    //Corners
    self.Preview.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    self.Preview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    //Background
    self.Preview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    grad.frame = self.Preview.bounds;
    grad.colors = [[[Kleuren sharedInstance] kleurenArray] objectForKey:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"Kleur"]];

    [self.Preview.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];

    //Text
    self.optionOutlet.textColor = [Kleuren.sharedInstance.tekstKleurenArray objectForKey:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"TekstKleur"]];
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the `NSLog` from my sublayers from the view. How can i replace the old `CAGradientLayer` with the new one? Tried this:

```
[self.Preview.layer replaceSublayer:0 with:grad];

(
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0xcce9eb0>",
    "<CALayer: 0xccef760>"
)
```

**EDIT 2:**
After trying some more, i've noticed that the CAGradientLayer is just added and added on top? Maybe this is the problem?

```
(
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x170220100>",
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x170220e20>",
    "<CAGradientLayer: 0x170029f40>",
    "<CALayer: 0x17803d960>"
)
```

**EDIT 3:**
View hierarchy, so the `View` that is highlighted in the screenshot is the one with the background.
[image: View]

**EDIT 4:**

Tried this: but now it doesn't have a CALayer anymore:

```
[[self.Preview layer] replaceSublayer:[[[self.Preview layer] sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] with:grad];
```

So I would get the following error:

```
2014-07-08 18:57:18.365 ///[3324:60b] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
    Constraint: <NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0xe88e0b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' UILabel:0xe88dae0.left == UIView:0xe88da50.left + 20>
    Container hierarchy: 
<UIView: 0xe88da50; frame = (59 54; 202 202); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xe88dab0>>
   | <CAGradientLayer: 0xe88cd50> (layer)
    View not found in container hierarchy: <UILabel: 0xe88dae0; frame = (20 20; 162 162); text = 'Option'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xe88db90>>
    That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
```

So it seems to be that because the CALayer is deleted, the UILabel gives this error because it doesn't have a superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I've placed my `CAGradientLayer *grad;` in my implementation declaration between the `{}`

By placing the declaration in my implementation of my class. I could re-use the declaration, and not making a new instance each time by putting it in the setupCell.

```
@implementation class {
   CAGradientLayer *grad
}

-(void)setupCell{
   // Do stuff here with the gradient layer.
}
```

I do not know that this is the right explanation but it works. Was the last thing I came up on!

Comment: Could you explain this more? Are you saying that you moved the declaration of `grad` outside of the `setupCell` method?

Comment: I would recommend using a property rather than an instance variable (which is what you're doing here).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 [self.Preview.layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

after setupCell. This should redraw the layer

Comment: Thanks for the comment but still it does not work. I've noticed something, and edited my question. Could you have a look?

Comment: Is this all happening in your viewController?
What is the hierarchy of the views here? What is setupCell acting on?

Comment: As you can see the view is under my TableView Cells, I've edited my post with the Storyboard hierarchy

Comment: tableViewCells act differently. you need to reload the cell to activate the drawing. 
use 
    [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
where index is the index of the row you are trying to reload.

Comment: But it isn't actually in my tableViewCells, it's underneath it. but still in the tableview

Comment: Do you ever see the gradient? like - can you change it on load?

Answer (score 0):

Not immediately sure what your issue is.

The first thing that jumped out at me is that in your first **EDIT**, you misused `replaceSublayer:with:`. See [the documentation for that method for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/replaceSublayer%3awith%3a), but basically you used an integer literal when you need to pass a `CALayer` - I'm surprised the compiler didn't complain. The declaration of that method is:

```
- (void)replaceSublayer:(CALayer *)oldLayer with:(CALayer *)newLayer
```

To use this method correctly, you'll want to hold onto a reference to the gradient layer. Maybe make a new property called `grad` and store it there. Later, when you want to replace it, pass `self.grad` into `replaceSublayer:with:` as `oldLayer`.

After you've fixed that, here are some things to check:

- Are you sure `setupCell` gets called when you think it does? Set a breakpoint there to check.
- Are you sure that when you recalculate the gradient layer, the colors have changed? Use a breakpoint to examine the value of `grad.colors` each time you pass through `setupCell`.

Comment: `setupCell` gets properly called, because in the same method I change my label color, and that is changed like I want to. Also the colors are updated, just checked the grad.colors and they are oke. When I pop one view controller in my navigation and go back, the color will have changed. Please check my new edit